# How can I display the contents of a txt file in a html file, WITH the requirement that I can format this text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to show the content of a txt file in an HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title><div style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 50px; color: blue">
    blabla</div></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>

<body>
<div style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 50px; color: blue">
    blabla</div>


    <p></p>
    <div style= "font-family: verdana; font-size: 24px; color: blue">blabla </div> 
    <object data="file:///C:/number.txt" type="text/plain" width="200" height="50"></object>
    <div style =  "font-family: verdana; font-size: 24px; color: blue"> blabla</div>
```

This works, but I cant change things like font or font-color. I tried div style, I tried it with CSS, also "!important" wasn't the solution.

The specific affected piece of code:

```
<object data="file:///C:/number.txt" type="text/plain" width="200" height="50"></object>
```

Q: How to I import the content of my txt file in my HTML page with the condition that I cant format the text?

Comment: have you tried adding the styles to the `object` tag itself, instead of the surrounding divs?

Comment: Is your html file also local (`file:///...`)?

Comment: Instead of a `file://` path, try to use a webserver and get it over http. This prevents tons of problems

Comment: @ADyson Like this?

<object style="font-family: verdana" data="file:///C:/number.txt" type="text/plain" width="200" height="50"></object>

This doensn't work.

Comment: @Walk Yes, also local.

Comment: Browsers are very restrictive about giving a site direct access to the local filesystem. Your text file is being read and imported, but converted to `<pre>` for security, in order to prevent code injection. The correct way to read a file is via a server. Run a local web server, ask it to read the file and send the content to the browser, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @Apolo thx, I'll try it!